# Postgres Recursive Data Extractor

Tags: database, postgresql

I know that most database management software has the ability to create a dependency graph where you see all the tables that have foreign-keys to all the other tables. The fact that this is available makes me think that there should be some tool or script that uses the same concept to extract a vertical slice of the actual data.

Basically, I want to be able to give a tool a specific row in a table, and then have it check the database for every other row in every other table that references the first one with a foreign key. And then it should repeat that process recursively, selecting all of the data that is in some way "connected" to the original row. Then I would like it to store a copy of all that data into its own database.

The purpose for this is to provide our developers a snapshot of all the data related to a specific customer so that they can debug with the same data set, without having to expose the entire production database to them.

So, is there any existing method for doing this sort of thing?

Thank you!

Comment: There can be circular dependencies, so don't look for a generic answer. Also, if the tables definitions are different, how can you copy these data into a single table?

Comment: In addition to recursively identifying all of the data dependent on the initial row, it will also be necessary to recursively identify the data on which all of the previously identified rows depend. Research algorithms for finding connected nodes in a directed graph.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Oh yeah, I didn't mean a single table. I meant a database. I'll correct my question.